# C# + Connect asynchronously and waiting in a loop for data

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

This kind of question has been asked a lot I guess, but I am still confused as to what I should be doing.

What I want is to connect asynchronously to a server (written by somebody else) in loop through waiting for data to be sent. When a message is receive it must go off and do something with that data, I figure using a Background Worker is probably best.

I don't however really understand the whole Callback thing and the example from msdn doesn't seem to work correctly. It just reads once and then closes. I need the connection to stay open waiting for messages to come through.

Am I doing things the right way round by connecting and waiting for messages, or should I be acting as the server side, allow a connection from a client and then receive the messages they send me?

Please a push in the right direction would be helpfull.

Regards,

Neill

Update 1:

Thanks for the replies all. I understand the need for the Callback function, but I am confused about the following code:

```
// Read data from the remote device.
        int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0) {
            // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
        state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer,0,bytesRead));

            // Get the rest of the data.
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer,0,StateObject.BufferSize,0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        } else {
            // All the data has arrived; put it in response.
            if (state.sb.Length > 1) {
                response = state.sb.ToString();
            }
            // Signal that all bytes have been received.
            receiveDone.Set();
        }
```

As I understand it, it receives data and stores it in sb. But is it then supposed to call itself again in case there is more data? My test data I receive is small, so everything is received on the first go, but if i put a break point on that code and step through, it doesnt call the Callback a second time, so:

```
response = state.sb.ToString();
```

is never hit.

And another thing I am unsure of is how to use Receive() in a loop so that my connection will just sit waiting for data indefinately, passing the data it receives along.

Is the Callback on a seperate thread? or should I use a background worker when data is received so it can go off and do what it needs to, and the connection can carry on listening for data?

Thanks for all the help.

Neill

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570151/why-wait-for-asynchronous-web-services-calls the accepted answer should help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming as you have tagged the question with sockets that you are using .Net sockets namespace. This supports async accept connection as well as async reads. The following links explains it Properly -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a.aspx

To explain I will copy  and paste code -

```
private static void Receive(Socket client) {
    try {
        // Create the state object.
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = client;

        // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.
        client.BeginReceive( state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

The receive function above is called when a successful connection with the server is established. Notice the call to BeginReceive it takes a new AsyncCallback functiona as a parameter. Whenever there is data sent by the server this function (ReceiveCallBack) will be called which will do something with is it. This just works!

Hope this helps.